# How would semantic segmentation work with a non convolutional neural network

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, generative-adversarial-networks

Listening to lectures, convolutional neural network seems to be an improvement over a simple neural network, where for example, you take every pixel in the image, flatten it to a vector, and feed it to ANN with a couple layers. Therefore semantic segmentation should be possible to perform on a classic ANN.

I dont understand exactly how a CNN can classify each pixel in the image to do semantic segmentation.

The way semantic segmentation is explained in lectures is the output of the CNN is fed into it backwards, is that the same as with GAN?

If the output of a CNN is a value between 0 and 1 for each class, how exactly can those values be fed back through a CNN backwards to classify each pixel in the image? Through back propagation?

My understanding is that it should be possible to do the same to a regular ANN described above. 
Can someone explain why or why not it wouldn't be possible, and how semantic segmentation feeds output back through network to classify each pixel

Thanks,